# Why doesn't `sam local start-api` transform the http request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I use `sam local start-api` to launch my lambda in local. And I use this command `curl --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/hello` to send POST request with JSON data to this lambda.

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('event body:', event);
    try {
        // const ret = await axios(url);
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world',
                // location: ret.data.trim()
            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    return response
};
```

The event is printed as a http request object like:

```
  body: '{"url": "http://"}',
  resource: '/hello',
  requestContext: 
...
```

But when I deploy the function to lambda and send the request via API-GATEWAY, the data printed is the body `{"url": "http://"}`.
I looks like API Gateway does a transform on the request but the local server doesn't. How can I make the local server run as the same way as API Gateway?

Below is SAM template file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Comment: How do you deploy your code and configuration and how does the configuration for API Gateway look like?

Comment: I added the SAM template file in the original question

Comment: Asked 2 years ago, and still no answer